# What is the correct org configuration for a long standing demo account?

Tags: developer-edition, environment-hub, trialforce

We use a demo org to showcase our application. The problem we have is that SFDC closes demo orgs after 12 months (with a message saying "Your 30 day trial has ended"). Our application takes a bit of time to setup and configure as well as some custom code to keep the data fresh. I'm not enjoying having to do it all over again every 12 months. Ideally we'd also like to have as many user accounts as possible, as that helps the demo.

We use the Environment Hub to create orgs, but what is the best configuration to use given our criteria? The options are development, test/demo, and trialforce.

Should we use a dev org and try to file a case to get more users (I think it only comes with 2 or 3) or go with a test/demo org and submit a case to get the expiration extended or removed? I have no experience with trialforce or if that would be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the only real option is to set the org up as a demo org. It WILL expire after 12 months but you can log a case ahead of expiration asking that they extend the org. They will not remove the expiration completely, so you'll have to keep doing this every 12 months or so.

It's unfortunate, but I can understand them not wanting to have a bunch of demo orgs that aren't being used clogging up their systems.